# Quick jQuery fadeTo/fadeIn syntax

Tags: jquery

I've got this line, but I've tried adding the fade in, or fadeto part, it's not having any effect, so I presume it's not written correctly...

```
$(".bold_link").replaceWith('<span class="bold_link">No Virus Found! <img src="/images/virus-tick.png" alt=""/></span>').fadeTo('slow', 1);
```

The entire code, if it's needed is:

```
$(function() {
$('.bold_link').click(function(e){
    $("#vc_icon").attr('src',"/images/virus-checking.gif");
    e.preventDefault();
    var shortname = "<?php echo $shortname; ?>";
    $.get("/virus-check.php?ajax", {sn: shortname}, function(data){
        if(data == '"Safe"'){
            $(".bold_link").replaceWith('<span class="bold_link">No Virus Found! <img src="/images/virus-tick.png" alt=""/></span>').fadeTo('slow', 1);
        }
        else{
            $(".bold_link").replaceWith('<span class="bold_link"><img src="/images/virus-cross.png" alt=""/> Infection Detected!<br />File no longer available for download.<br />Administrators have been notified.</span>');
        }
    });
});
```

});

Which when a link is clicked, jquery send an ajax request to the server, which scans a file, and returns a result, "Safe" if so, and else if not. The jQuery responds accordingly. I just want it to look a little fancier with a fade in to the result...

Any help would be great.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do a fadeOut first so that the fadeIn will be noticable

```
$('.bold_link').click(function(e){
    $("#vc_icon").attr('src',"/images/virus-checking.gif");
    e.preventDefault();
    var shortname = "<?php echo $shortname; ?>";

    $(".bold_link").fadeOut(500,function(){

     $.get("/virus-check.php?ajax", {sn: shortname}, function(data){
      if(data == '"Safe"'){
                $(".bold_link").replaceWith('<span class="bold_link">No Virus Found! <img src="/images/virus-tick.png" alt=""/></span>').fadeIn('slow');
            }
            else{
                $(".bold_link").replaceWith('<span class="bold_link"><img src="/images/virus-cross.png" alt=""/> Infection Detected!<br />File no longer available for download.<br />Administrators have been notified.</span>').fadeIn('slow');
            }
     });

    });
});
```

Comment: Hi, None of these effects are working... I can't get any kind of transition to work, not even slideUp(); is working. :(

Comment: You sure you have jQuery loaded ? are u getting any script errors ?

Comment: Hi, Yes, jQuery is doing everything else, the replaceWith etc... just not any animation. :(

Answer (score 1):

Write a seperate line `$(".bold_link").fadeOut();` It will work :)

Comment: Hi, None of these effects are working... I can't get any kind of transition to work, not even slideUp(); is working. :(